# web scraping in imdb using R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, imdb

I want to find the link to the top 250 movies in imdb. I decided to find a common pattern by viewing the HTML source code. I found "chttp" but I am not sure if it will get me anywhere. How can I find a pattern to construct the links upon it?

```
require("XML")
imdb="http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?sort=ir,desc"
imdb.page=readLines(imdb)
g = grep(pattern = "chttp", x = imdb_page) 
imdb.lines=imdb.page[g]
```

Here's an example output:

```
> imdb.lines[1]
[1] "      <h3><a href=\"/chart/?ref_=chttp_cht\" >IMDb Charts</a></h3>"
```

My main problem is trying to figure out the link(URL) for each of the 250 top movies based on the code I have already written. I basically don't know what's the next step. Also I am not sure the pattern I used the grep command for "chttp" is a good one at all or not.

So according to results starting from index 3 the movie titles are on the odd indices:

```
> imdb.lines[1]
[1] "      <h3><a href=\"/chart/?ref_=chttp_cht\" >IMDb Charts</a></h3>"
> imdb.lines[2]
[1] "  <td class=\"posterColumn\"><a href=\"/title/tt0111161/?ref_=chttp_tt_1\" ><img src=\"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_SX34_CR0,0,34,50_.jpg\" width=\"34\" height=\"50\" />"
> imdb.lines[3]
[1] "    <a href=\"/title/tt0111161/?ref_=chttp_tt_1\" title=\"Frank Darabont (dir.), Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman\" >The Shawshank Redemption</a>"
> imdb.lines[6]
[1] "  <td class=\"posterColumn\"><a href=\"/title/tt0071562/?ref_=chttp_tt_3\" ><img src=\"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNDc2NTM3MzU1Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX34_CR0,0,34,50_.jpg\" width=\"34\" height=\"50\" />"
> imdb.lines[4]
[1] "  <td class=\"posterColumn\"><a href=\"/title/tt0068646/?ref_=chttp_tt_2\" ><img src=\"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyMjcyNDI4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX34_CR0,0,34,50_.jpg\" width=\"34\" height=\"50\" />"
> imdb.lines[5]
[1] "    <a href=\"/title/tt0068646/?ref_=chttp_tt_2\" title=\"Francis Ford Coppola (dir.), Marlon Brando, Al Pacino\" >The Godfather</a>"
> imdb.lines[7]
[1] "    <a href=\"/title/tt0071562/?ref_=chttp_tt_3\" title=\"Francis Ford Coppola (dir.), Al Pacino, Robert De Niro\" >The Godfather: Part II</a>"
> imdb.lines[9]
[1] "    <a href=\"/title/tt0468569/?ref_=chttp_tt_4\" title=\"Christopher Nolan (dir.), Christian Bale, Heath Ledger\" >The Dark Knight</a>"
> imdb.lines[10]
[1] "  <td class=\"posterColumn\"><a href=\"/title/tt0110912/?ref_=chttp_tt_5\" ><img src=\"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE0ODk2NjczOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDQ0NDg4._V1_SY50_CR0,0,34,50_.jpg\" width=\"34\" height=\"50\" />"
```

Comment: I have no idea why this is put on hold as off-topic!!!

Comment: This is pretty straightforward with `xpath`. For titles, try: `library(XML);
tt <- htmlParse('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?sort=ir,desc');
xpathSApply(tt, "//td[@class='titleColumn']//a", xmlValue)`. Also look at `xpathSApply(tt, "//td[@class='titleColumn']//a", xmlAttrs)`.

Comment: I liked this but I need the URLs not the movie names. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry - my speedreading of your question. I edited the above comment. The first row of the result of the second code block gives the urls. i.e. `xpathSApply(tt, "//td[@class='titleColumn']//a", xmlAttrs)[1, ]`.

Comment: See my previous comment. Just subset the matrix to the first row. Or `cbind` the titles to the transposed  (i.e. `t()`) attributes matrix.

Comment: Can you please add this as answer?

Comment: They opened the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xpath` makes jobs like this trivial.

```
library(XML)
tt <- htmlParse('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?sort=ir,desc')
cbind(xpathSApply(tt, "//td[@class='titleColumn']//a", xmlValue),
           t(xpathSApply(tt, "//td[@class='titleColumn']//a", xmlAttrs)))
```

The first argument to `cbind` returns titles (the text between the `a` tags) and the second returns the anchors' attributes (href and title, the latter of which in this case contains details about the films' directors).

Comment: just a quick question. How can I extract just something like `tt0468569` from the URL?

Comment: There are a couple of ways, but `sub` is pretty good for that: `sub('.*/title/(.*)/.*', '\\1', s)`, where `s` is a vector of strings that you want to do that for, e.g. the url column of the output of my solution. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html) for more details on regular expressions. The `stringr` package has some convenience functions for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the [alternative interfaces](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces)?

**Edit #1**: I have looked into some of the files and there don't seem to be any links or even the imdb ID, there should be another way though.

**Edit #2**: OK, there is no other way apparently, but somebody already did something. E.g. [this guy](https://gist.github.com/Cyph0n/3067482); have a look.

Comment: Thank you. I liked this answer!